# First documented beneficial mutation?

Tags: evolution, history

I've been reading up on beneficial mutations, and am curious when we discovered and documented the first one.

Can anyone point me to the first documented beneficial mutation?

---

Per request, let me try to clarify my answer a bit.
I know that we've been aware of mutations perhaps as long ago as the 1930s (I believe it was R.A Fisher who was one of the first to talk about them??).

I have read various documented beneficial mutations since then, such as lactase example in humans, or cit+ in E.Coli.

What I'm curious about is when it was that we first identified and documented (scientific paper or article) an observed beneficial mutation, in any organism (not just humans).

So yes, Remi.b, your wording would have been what I was looking for:
"what is the first article that has documented a beneficial mutation, in any organism"

Does this clarify it enough?

Comment: You think about things like the mutation which activates lactase in people of european ancestry permanently?

Comment: Do you mean the first documentation (no matter if mutation was earliest exactly known), or earliest exactly known such mutation (which has been documented at any time)?

Comment: I am not really sure what kind of observation you are interested in? If we see a sweep just like for the lactase example in humans? Or are you looking for a mutation that appeared in a lab and that has directly been shown to be beneficial? And as Hyde said did you actually mean "what is the oldest beneficial mutation we know" or "what is the first article that has documented a beneficial mutation". In both case, the question needs editing I think, to make clear what kind of observation you are interested in.

Comment: I'm not even sure if you mean *in humans* or *ever*. This question is unclear. As others have said, it really needs to be narrowed down in its scope. This could mean nearly anything.

Comment: [E. coli using citrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._coli_long-term_evolution_experiment) might be the best document beneficial mutation.

Comment: @user137 - there are many examples of beneficial mutations. The problem is that it's unclear what the OP is asking.

Comment: It's a valid question, just needs refinement and then it can be re-opened for sure

Comment: Earliest beneficial mutation discovered by humans is what I guess OP is interested in, which I think is of no great relevance. Mutations happen all the time and beneficial mutations are selected in the evolutionary process. Which was the first example in the textbook doesn't make any great sense to me.

Comment: What search parameters have you tried to find the paper?

Comment: Good Gravy:  I didn't save my exact search text, but a lot along the lines of 'history of beneficial mutations', and 'first discovered beneficial mutations'.  I was getting no-where.  I figured I'd turn to a place like this, hoping someone here could point me in the right direction.

Comment: I found a list of documented beneficial mutations by typing in google "beneficial mutations". It was the fourth link. (http://www.gate.net/~rwms/EvoMutations.html)

Check the years and find the one which interests you. All of them are very well vulgarized and all their sources are cited.